# How does Ethereum handle a netsplit? Or say a major outage where undersea cables are severed rendering 1/3 or more nodes offline

Tags: go-ethereum

How does Ethereum handle a netsplit? Or say a major outage where undersea cables are severed rendering 1/3 or more nodes offline.

Does transaaction sent continue to be processed by the existing full nodes/miners or will the network grind to a halt?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Ethereum is a proof-of-work network which miners join and leave freely. Both sides of the split would contine building on their own chains, albeit at lower speed (in proportion to their share of the previous hashpower) until the difficulty adjusted. When the networks were joined again, the chain with less mining power would be orphaned and all nodes would converge on the chain that had the majority of the hashpower.

This will not necessary apply to the proof-of-stake design that Ethereum ultimately adopts.